# TypeScript, MongoDB and Reference Issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I've got a NodeJS app (built in Visual Studio) which uses TypeScript, and MongoDB.

I've written a small library which wraps the MongoDB driver in some TypeScript classes and just today it started acting up.

If I include this line at the top of one of my library files:

```
/// <reference path='./_scripts/typings/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts' />
```

it build *briefly*, before begining to complain about "Duplicate identifier"s, and lots of them, for example:

```
Error   6   Type name 'Transform' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for '"stream".Transform'.
Error   7   Type name 'events.EventEmitter' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'events.EventEmitter'.
Error   8   Duplicate identifier 'errno'.
Error   9   Duplicate identifier 'code'.
Error   10  Duplicate identifier 'path'.
```

So I take that out, and everything is *briefly* ok, until I start seeing issues reported around this line:

```
import mongodbNS = require('mongodb');
```

If I were to then remove that line, I would see errors with things like:

```
public Connect: () => Promise<mongodbNS.Db>;
```

I can muddle through by adding a removing things and taking advantage of the brief window of compilability which opens up - but clearly this is not the way.

What is?

Comment: an example of a `duplicate identifier` error message would be great

Comment: I'm using Node Tools for VS 2013, and they all come from node.d.ts.    I've added some examples above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and they all come from node.d.ts

This is happening because you have *two* versions of `node.d.ts` (i.e. different files on disk) in your project.

Comment: That occurred to me as well, so I did a search and of course there are two.  But they are both part of other d.ts files: socket.io.d.ts, and mongodb.d.ts, which are both used in the solution.  So, which one do I get rid of?

Comment: @Michael the older one. They should be compatible.

Comment: And then fix the reference in the one that was referencing the older version

Comment: They are in two different projects in the solution, each one referencing a project-local version of node.d.ts, each of which says "// Type definitions for Node.js v0.10.1" - so which is older?  This seems like a likely cause of the problem, but something isn't adding up.

Comment: If you have two version of the same file in a solution, I recommend moving your build outside visual studio e.g. https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts (disclosure : maintainer)

Comment: That would apply then, potentially, to any solution with multiple node projects, as node.d.ts gets added automatically.  Should I mod one of those d.ts files and remove the node reference, or...?

Comment: If you can, *delete* one of them and then go from there

Comment: Sorry - delete the actual node.d.ts file, or delete the reference to it?  I only need one reference to it in the solution, is that correct?  The actual files themselves don't matter.  Or are they getting auto-imported or some such?

Comment: Either a.) you have 2 versions in the solution or b) files in your solution are referencing the different version. In either case delete 1

Comment: I was able to remove the reference to node.d.ts in the mongodb.d.ts file (it doesn't appear to be necessary) and that seems to have made the problem go away.